# Alogrithm for computing $s_k=z_1^k+\cdots +z_n^k$, where $z_i$'s are roots of polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms

Consider $P(x)=(x-z_1)(x-z_2)\cdots (x-z_n)\in\mathbb{R}[x]$, where $z_i$'s $\in \mathbb{C}$ are root of polynomial. As I know from Viete theorem
$$s_k=z_1^k+\cdots +z_n^k$$
being a symmetric function, and can be expressed in terms of the coefficients of polynomial. But how can I compute $s_k$ just by coefficents, without knowing the roots?. Are there any formula, or algorithms (maybe for sequences $s_k,s_{k-1},s_{k-2}$) for computing $s_k$?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities

Answer (score 2):

$$
P(x) = (x-z_1) \cdots (x-z_n)\\
= x^n - e_1 (z_1 \cdots z_n) x^{n-1} + e_2 (z_1 \cdots z_n) x^{n-2} + \cdots + (-1)^n e_n (z_1 \cdots z_n)\\
$$

So knowing the coefficients of the polynomial means you know the elementary symmetric polynomials of the $z_i$. You want the power sum's instead. What you call $s_k$ are more usually called $p_k$ with $p$ for power.

The change of one form of symmetric polynomials to another are known as Newton identities.

I am going to leave out the $z_i$ from know on, so $e_k$ means $k$'th elementary symmetric function of the $z_i$ without making those $z_i$ explicit.

$$
p_k = (-1)^k k e_k + \sum_{i=1}^{k-1} (-1)^{k+1-i} e_{k-i} p_i
$$

This gets you the $p_k$ for $1 \leq k \leq n$.

So you can evaluate the $p_1$, then $p_2$ and then so on inductively.

Answer (score 1):

Write $f(x) = x^{n}  - s_{1}x^{n-1} + s_{2} x^{n-2} +\cdots + (-1)^{n} s_{n}$. Let $\alpha_{k}$ be the roots of $f(x)$. Then $f(\alpha_{k}) = 0, k = 1, 2, \cdots, n$.

Consider $g_{i} (x) = x^{i-n} f(x)$. Note that $0 = g_{i}(\alpha_{k})  = \alpha_{k}^{i} - s_{1}\alpha_{k}^{i-1} + \cdots +  (-1)^{n} s_{n} \alpha_{k}^{i-n}$, there are $n$ of such equations. We sum all of the n equations and group them using the definition of $p_{i}$.

We get: $0 = \sum_{k=1}^{n} g_{i}(\alpha_{k}) = p_{i} - s_{1} p_{i-1} + \cdots + (-1)^{n}s_{n}p_{i-n}$, which gives the formula for $p_{i}$ by noting $p_{i -n}$ is defined for $i = n$ so that $(-1)^{n}s_{n}p_{i-n} = (-1)^{i}is_{i}$.